# How to edit (PHP) file more than 1MB of size in cPanel File manage?

Tags: php, cpanel, file-manager

How to edit (PHP) file more than 1MB of size in cPanel File manage ?

I tried to edit 1 mb. php file using cPanel file namage. But menu edit still disable. How can setting cPanel File manage for edit file that mosr than 1 mb ?

Comment: did you check the file permission ?

Comment: yes, checked 644 .....

Comment: Use filezilla ftp client to edit the file that will be better because sometimes some cpanel can not load large file

Comment: I'm sure that there is nothing like, cPanel restricts file editing of size above 1MB . There must be some other thing that blocks this from processing . Instead of digging this way search in other way round that whether anything blocks this .

Also you can do as @ManozBiswas said .